# onClick detection for both an li and button nested within li

Tags: javascript, reactjs

so i'm trying to implement the line-through feature while having a delete button. clicking on the li text crosses out the item, and clicking on the del button removes it.

functionally, it works. the issue is when I delete an itme, say "2", it will apply the line-through style to the list item below it. i'm guessing this is because "onClick" is detected twice - both inside the list item and the button (because the button is technically nested within the list item). the moment I press on the DEL button for 2, the onClick is detected for list item 3, applying the line-through style. what would be the best way to go about correcting this?

my code with an App component and ListItem component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ListItem from "./ListItem";
 
function App() {
  const [inputText, setInputText] = useState("");
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
 
  function handleChange(event) {
    const newValue = event.target.value;
    setInputText(newValue);
  }
 
  function addItem() {
    setItems((prevItems) => {
      return [...prevItems, inputText];
    });
    setInputText("");
  }
 
  function deleteItem(id) {
    setItems((prevItems) => {
      return prevItems.filter((item, index) => {
        return index !== id;
      });
    });
  }
 
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="heading">
        <h1>To-Do List</h1>
      </div>
      <div className="form">
        <input onChange={handleChange} type="text" value={inputText} />
        <button onClick={addItem}>
          <span>Add</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <ul>
          {items.map((todoItem, index) => (
            <ListItem
              key={index}
              id={index}
              item={todoItem}
              delete={deleteItem}
            />
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
 
export default App;
 
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
 
import React, { useState } from "react";
 
function ListItem(props) {
  const [clickedOn, setClickedOn] = useState(false);
 
  function handleClick() {
    setClickedOn((prevValue) => {
      return !prevValue;
    });
  }
 
  return (
    <div>
      <li
        onClick={handleClick}
        style={{ textDecoration: clickedOn ? "line-through" : "none" }}
      >
        {props.item}
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            props.delete(props.id);
          }}
          style={{ float: "right" }}
        >
          <span>Del</span>
        </button>
      </li>
    </div>
  );
}
 
export default ListItem;
```

Answer (score 1):

As you already wrote, user events are propagated up the DOM tree. To stop the propagation, you can use `event.stopPropagation()` [ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) in your event handler

```js
        <button
          onClick={(event) => {
            event.stopPropagation();
            props.delete(props.id);
          }}
          style={{ float: "right" }}
        >
```

Comment: ok thank you. i added that to my code and that solved the original issue. now, let's say I have items 1, 2, 3 and I click on 2 to apply line-through. when i delete 2, item 3 will take its place and now has a line-through applied. do I have to add event.stopPropagation somewhere in the li onClick handler as well?